# How to infer a complete map of all the sub-stores, their actions, and their payloads?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

**TL;DR**: In a composite store, is there a way to infer all actions with their payloads grouped by the sub-store they are related to in a single type entity (e.g., `interface`)?

---

I have set up a Redux store with a couple of sub-stores, the total picture is similar to this:

- there is an action `setAppLoading(isLoading :boolean)` that sets `state.app.loading` to the `action.payload`;
- there is an action `setUserName(name: string | null)` that also sets `state.user.name` to the `action.payload` (the name is nullable, — e.g., if user does not exist);
- there is an action `logOut()` that does some API stuff and then calls `setUserName(null)`;

What I want to achieve in the end is to infer the complete structure of the store, as follows:

```
interface ActionsMap {
  app: {
    setAppLoading(isLoading: boolean): void
  }
  user: {
    setUserName(name: string | null): void
    logOut(): void
  }
}
```

**Is it possible to infer this type from already existing entities (see below)?** I want to define things once, and I don't want to re-export things, because I will definitely have situations when I have created an action but forgot to refer to it in other places.

---

I already have a `store` instance (created with `configureStore()` and `combineReducers()`) that is properly typed, and I can already infer all sub-store names from it:

```
type State = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>

// omitting the internal key `typeof $CombinedState`
type SubStoreName = Extract<keyof State, string>
```

For each store separately there is also already a collection of all related actions, that is also properly typed:

```
import * as appActions from 'store/app/actions'
import * as userActions from 'store/user/actions'

dispatch(appActions.setAppLoading(true))
dispatch(userActions.logOut())
```

---

So far, the closest thing that I have came up with is this:

```
const actionsMap = {
  app: appActions,
  game: gameActions,
} satisfies Record<SubStoreName, unknown>

type ActionsMap = typeof actionsMap
```

This requires me to "re-export things", which I don't want, but it also will notify me if I forget to re-export something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and it's probably also not the best way of thinking.
While in slices, there is often an action "owned" by that slice, that action can still be listened to by all the reducers in your application.

It's much better to think in ways of "this event happened in my application" instead of "this action was sent to that reducer".

Think in events, not setters. See the [Redux Style Guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#model-actions-as-events-not-setters) on the topic.

Comment: The example I have given does not reflect what I have in the actual app. Actually, the majority of the app actions are "event" actions (such as `logOut` in this case), but it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Well, the answer itself is "no, that's not possible". The store type only knows about reducer types, not about action types, or how they are related to slices you may or may not have in there. I just thought I'd provide context why it is probably generally not a good idea on how to attempt this.